# Searching strings between unrelated tables

Tags: string, text, powerbi, dax, lookup-tables

I'm trying to categorize my service requests based on key words which can be found either in the request description or request solution. My list of keywords is independent from my database. So I can't come up with the code necessary to lookup various text strings from one table in the columns of another (non-related) table.
My first table (called Comp_build) has 4 columns (each for Installs, Instructions, Security, and Troubleshoot) and below is a sample of it with keywords
Install        Troubleshoot             Security              Instructions
request        error                    Security driven       create automated
onboarding     fail                                           package
deploy

My second table (called Comp_determination) has 3 columns: Category (calculated column), SR Description, SR Solution

I've played around with:
SWITCH
TRUE
IF
FIND
SEARCH
SUMX
CALCULATE

This is the closest I've been able to find (https://powerpivotpro.com/2014/01/containsx-finding-if-a-value-in-table-1-has-a-matching-value-in-table-2/) but the results aren't consistent. it seems to work correctly if I'm looking up my install keywords but if I try with security keywords, my entire column Category is populated with "Security"

category = IF(SUMX(comp_build,FIND(comp_build[Install],comp_determination[SR Description],,0))>0,"Installations","")

I want to identify all cases bases on keywords and assign them a request category. Since we receive essentially 4 major categories of requests, I have keywords for each category - located in a separate table and each in their column. Additionally, I can search for the key words in two places - either in the request description or the request solution.

Comment: Please provide an example of your tables with some data in it to make your problem better understandable.

Comment: Can I upload text files?

Comment: No, but some sample data in text would be just fine.

Comment: Table one
Name: Comp_build (csv type)
Col 1 name: Install
Col 1 ex: request, install, require, informatics account employee transfer, need, informatics account change, employee onboarding, advertisied, deployed, installed
Col 2 name: Troubleshoot
Col 1 ex: error, fail, doesn't work, problem
Col 3 name: Security
Col 3 ex: IT Security Driven
Col 4 name: Instructions
Col 4 ex: create automated, create an automated, package, create

Comment: Table two
Name: Comp_determination (SQL database, csv)
Col 1 name: Category (calculated column)
Col 2 name: SR Description
Col 2 ex: '...need to have SQL Developer installed...', '...have encountered difficulties...', '...Please help to install...', '...I need a software...', '...SSIS component installation...', "IT Security Driven', '...Please create an automate package for software...'
Col 3 name: SR Solution
Col 3 ex: '...software has been advertised...', 'added to the security group', '...Packaged and tested', '...installed...'

Comment: So I managed to make it work partially.

Comment: So I managed to make it work - partially. Here's part of the code I'm using (too long to post it all and still be legible):
Assignment Component built = 
     if(
sumx(Comp_build,
find(
upper('comp_build'[installations]),
upper(Bulk[SR Description])
,,0)) > 0,
"Installation",
     if(
sumx(Comp_build,
find(
upper('comp_build'[installations]),
upper(Bulk[SR Solution])
,,0)) > 0,
"Installation",
     if(
sumx(Comp_build,
find(
upper('Comp_build'[Instructions]),
upper(Bulk[SR Description])
,,0)) > 0,

...

Comment: My problem now is that it only seems to look at the first 4 if statements and doesn't bother going through the remaining conditions BUT I don't get any error messages.